# serving pdfjs PDFs over nginx

Tags: nginx, pdf.js

I am looking to serve [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) using nginx, but Iam having trouble with the example so far. So, I do the following:

```
git clone git://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js.git /some/location/pdfjs
cd /some/location/pdfjs
```

.. Now, I set up my nginx config file like so:

```
server {
    listen 8181 default_server;
    listen [::]:8181 default_server ipv6only=on;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

root /some/location/pdfjs/web;
index viewer.html;

access_log  /some/location/access.log;
error_log  /some/location/error.log;

location / {

}

   }
```

When I run nginx now, I the PDF does not show up. I do see the pdf.js outer canvas though - just not serving the PDF file.

When I look at the error messages, I see:

```
    2014/12/10 16:28:32 [error] 15549#0: *1 open() "/some/location/pdfjs/web/external/webL10n/l10n.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /external/webL10n/l10n.js HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8181", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8181/"
    2014/12/10 16:28:32 [error] 15549#0: *2 open() "/some/location/pdfjs/web/src/shared/util.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /src/shared/util.js HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8181", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8181/"
    2014/12/10 16:28:32 [error] 15549#0: *3 open() "/some/location/pdfjs/web/src/display/api.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /src/display/api.js HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8181", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8181/"
    2014/12/10 16:28:32 [error] 15549#0: *4 open() "/some/location/pdfjs/web/src/display/metadata.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /src/display/metadata.js HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8181", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8181/"
    2014/12/10 16:28:32 [error] 15549#0: *5 open() "/some/location/pdfjs/web/src/display/canvas.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /src/display/canvas.js HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8181", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8181/"
    2014/12/10 16:28:32 [error] 15549#0: *6 open() "/some/location/pdfjs/web/src/display/webgl.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /src/display/webgl.js HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8181", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8181/"
    2014/12/10 16:28:32 [error] 15549#0: *1 open() "/some/location/pdfjs/web/src/display/pattern_helper.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /src/display/pattern_helper.js HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8181", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8181/"
    2014/12/10 16:28:32 [error] 15549#0: *2 open() "/some/location/pdfjs/web/src/display/font_loader.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /src/display/font_loader.js HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8181", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8181/"
    2014/12/10 16:28:32 [error] 15549#0: *3 open() "/some/location/pdfjs/web/src/display/annotation_helper.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /src/display/annotation_helper.js HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8181", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8181/"
```

Not sure if this has got to do with serving the actually PDF - would appreciate any suggestions to solve this.

Comment: Your root shall be /some/location/pdfjs (without web part).

Comment: Also use release version at http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download

Comment: @async5: I tried your modification: `root /home/foo/pdfjs/;
index viewer.html;` and also `root /home/foo/pdfjs/;
index web/viewer.html;` both just give me a 404.. Well, the dev version on ghub should be more current than the stable Id have thought anyway..Basically, I am looking for a way to serve pdfjs pdfs via nginx..